# Use includes of adjacent subproject in cmake

Tags: api, include, cmake, subdirectory

I develop a project which consisting of several shared libraries and build it with CMake.
Each library is built via `add_subdirectory()`.

What is the best way to add all the API headers of the fist library to the CMakeLists.txt of the second?

Comment: Here, I mean the case when I do not want to link API-providing libraries, I just need to get an access to headers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Encode the include directories in the target itself:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#include-directories-and-usage-requirements

That doc is new, but the target_include_directories command exists since CMake 2.8.11. Use it with the INTERFACE or PUBLIC option.

Answer (score 4):

To make an answer of **steveire** complete:

for the library which exports API we should write

```
target_include_directories("target_with_api" INTERFACE "path_to_api_includes")
```

and for the library which uses this API we write

```
target_include_directories("api_client_target_name" PRIVATE
             $<TARGET_PROPERTY:"target_with_api",INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>)
```

where `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:"target_with_api",INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>)` returns us target property assigned to the library with API

Comment: What? No! That's wrong. You don't need target_include_directories at the consume-site. Just use target_link_libraries. That consumes the include directories from the specified targets.

Comment: @steveire Sorry, I have not emphasized it - I do not need to link libraries, I just need to access the API headers. In my particular case libraries are loaded manually

Comment: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#interface-libraries

Comment: ➕1 this is especially useful when using "object libraries"