# Cmake Shared library

Tags: makefile, cmake

I am learning CMake but I am struggling to understand how to link a binary file to a shared library and then install these files in a release folder.

These is the structure of my project:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── build
├── main
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cpp
├── release
|_______bin 
│   ├── include
│   │   └── math.h
│   └── lib
│       └── libmathLib.dylib
└── shared_lib
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── include
    │   └── math.h
    └── src
        └── math.cpp
```

In the root CMakeLists.txt I've defined the project settings and the subdirectory.

Root CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project (Math)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

set(MAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(shared_lib)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(main)
```

Main CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main LINK_PUBLIC mathLib)
```

Math lib ( shared lib )

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_library(mathLib SHARED src/math.cpp)

install(TARGETS mathLib DESTINATION /Users/giuseppe/development/cmake/release/lib LIBRARY NAMELINK_ONLY)
install(FILES include/math.h DESTINATION /Users/giuseppe/development/cmake/release/include)
```

When I build the project with Make, it doesn't link main.o to the shared library. Error :

```
Scanning dependencies of target mathLib
[ 50%] Building CXX object shared_lib/CMakeFiles/mathLib.dir/src/math.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library libmathLib.dylib
[ 50%] Built target mathLib
Scanning dependencies of target main
[100%] Building CXX object main/CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
/Users/giuseppe/development/cmake/main/main.cpp:8:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'sum'
  count << sum(5,6) << endl;
           ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [main/CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [main/CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Release phase:

How can I make sure that the builds in the bin folder within the release folder use the shared lib in 'path/release/lib'? Possibly using a relative path such as '../lib/' ?

Comment: Your executable's name is `math`, and you are trying to link to a target named `main`. Is this a typo?

Comment: @HeyYO thanks, yes it is a typo.

Comment: `use of undeclared identifier` is a compiler error, not linker. There is a problem with your includes. Are you sure `math.h` is in your include path? I'm assuming this is the file that declares `sum()` .

Comment: Oh by the way, `math.h` is the name of the C standard math library. Don't use this name for your own files!

Comment: it was including the standard math lib. Now I changed the name to my_math.h and it cannot find the header file

Answer (score 0):

You must add include directory for library to `main/CMakeLists.txt`. Adding it to `shared_lib/CMakeLists.txt` is not enough. Try this line:

```
include_directories("../shared_lib/include")
```

Comment: Shouldn't Cmake work out that path automatically because I am setting `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)` in shared_lib/CMakeList.txt?

Comment: No. Using a parent `CMakeList.txt` file doesn't merge your sub CmakeLists.txt files together. They are still separate projects. If you want to declare your includes once, you can use a single CMakeList.txt file.

Comment: That's what I would like to do. For example, would be a good idea to declare all includes in the top level CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. There is a reason you are dividing your project into separate parts. One of them is to easier dependency management. When you have all your includes in one file, it won't be clear which sub project depends on which. Have a look at [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440698/use-includes-of-adjacent-subproject-in-cmake), maybe this is what you want.

Comment: What I needed was `target_include_directories(mathLib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)` in shared_lib/CMakeLists.txt so that its header files are accessible when compiling main.cpp